# VHDL is there a way to make an automated time-based sequence?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to move a robot arm via FPGA board. The communication is working just fine but I want to make an automated sequence that I would be able to modify on fly. Basically what I need is to be able to code sequentially what follows:

```
PA0 <= PA1; (for 2s)
PA2 <= PA5; (for 3,5s)
PA4 <= PA3; (for 3s)
PA2 <= PA1; (for 2s)
```

in a form of data vector or in a case block just to keep it simple and be able to add/change signals and time for which those signals will be propagated.

I've tried this with simple timer and if statements but it's nowhere near perfect and I'm not able to change signal's propagation time without conversing it to binary and adding to existing time counter. It simply looks messy. And I can't change states in case based on time passed.

EDIT:

As asked I'm including piece of code with declarations (LEDs are just for tests).

CODE:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity abra is

port
    (
    PA0 : out std_logic ;
    PA2 : out std_logic;
    PA4 : out std_logic;
    PA6 : out std_logic;
    PA1 : in std_logic;
    PA3 : in std_logic;
    PA5 : in std_logic;
    PA7 : in std_logic;

    LED: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

        RST: in std_logic; --ROT_CENTER--
        CLK : in std_logic --50MHz clock--

    );
end abra;

architecture Behavioral of abra is

signal TIME_COUNTER : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal CNTR : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');


begin

control: process(CLK)
begin

if rising_edge(CLK) then

    if(TIME_COUNTER = b"00000000101111101011110000100000") then
        CNTR <= CNTR + 1; --should inc every 1s--
        TIME_COUNTER <= (others => '0');
    else
    TIME_COUNTER <= TIME_COUNTER + 1;
    end if;


    if( RST = '1' ) then
                    CNTR <= (others => '0');
                    LED <= "11111111";
    end if;

        PA0 <= '0';
        PA2 <= '0';
        PA4 <= '0';
        PA6 <= '0';

    -----------------

        if( CNTR >= "00000000" AND CNTR < "00000100") then
            PA6 <= PA5; --servo 1 / side up--
            LED <= b"00000001";
        end if;

        if( CNTR >= "00000100" AND CNTR < "00001011") then  
            PA4 <= PA3; --servo 3 / side down--
            LED <= b"00000010";
        end if;

        if( CNTR >= "00001011" AND CNTR < "00110000") then  
            PA2 <= PA1; -- servo 6 / side down--
            LED <= b"00000100";
        end if;

        if ( CNTR >= "00100000") then
            LED <= b"00000000";
        end if;

    ------------------

end if;
end process control;

end Behavioral;
```

UCF declarations:

```
NET "PA0"  LOC = "A13" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA2"  LOC = "B13" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA4"  LOC = "A14" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA6"  LOC = "B15" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA1"  LOC = "A15" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA3"  LOC = "A16" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA5"  LOC = "A17" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;
NET "PA7"  LOC = "B17" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = FAST | DRIVE = 8 ;

NET "RST"  LOC = "R13" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | PULLDOWN ;
NET "CLK" LOC = "E12"| IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 ;

NET "LED<0>" LOC = "W21" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<1>" LOC = "Y22" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<2>" LOC = "V20" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<3>" LOC = "V19" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<4>" LOC = "U19" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<5>" LOC = "U20" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<6>" LOC = "T19" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
NET "LED<7>" LOC = "R20" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | Drive = 8 ;
```

Comment: maybe you could show us one or both methods (along with declarations) and tell us what the adverse of 'no where near perfect' is. Your question is a bit abstract.

Comment: I added piece of code I wrote to test the robot arm. As seen here if I would want to add an action between any of those I'd have to change all the following if statements. And if I would want to make a sequence of 10+ movements it'd look messy plus time conversion is time-consuming.

Comment: Don't use std_logic_unsigned. Define time_counter as `unsigned`. You can compare unsigned to integer literal, code like `if time_counter = 123` is much better than `if time_counter = "1111011"` . Finally, instead of using a time counter at 50MHz, you may want to create a counter of half seconds. It's much nicer to have `if half_sec_cnt > 4` to verify if time is greater than 2 seconds...

Comment: Using integer instead of vector is a big help, thank you. So back to the question, is there a way to make time based sequence block which I would be able to modify without a need to change the rest of the states? Ideally I'd want to declare signals and time of propagation, then move to another state.

Comment: Usually, this is a job for a programable statemachine  (PSM) or 8-bit CPU like PicoBlaze. PicoBlaze supports reprogramming at runtime via JTAG.